# How to Encode an Image  for .NET Sockets

Tags: c#, image, proxy

I'm creating a simple proxy server. The problem I'm facing is that when I request an image, instead of getting (first 4 bytes):

```
ÿØÿà
```

I get:

```
ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
```

I'm using char array to store the data. Do I need to use a byte instead of char?

I'm using async sockets, this is what I have in onRecieve callback:

```
            System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            int charLen = d.GetChars(socketData.dataBuffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
```

Can anyone please point me at the right direction?

**UPDATE:**

I did use the socketData.buffer suggestion, but now all I get is numbers, no characters. This is what I'm doing:

1. Collecting all the data from socketData.buffer and place it into an List
2. Loop through the list and write out all the data to browser, like this:

   ```
    Stream clientStream = client.GetStream();
    Stream outStream = clientStream;
    StreamWriter myResponseWriter = new StreamWriter(outStream);

    for(int i=0; i<myList.Count; i++){
        myResponseWriter.Write(myList[i]);
    }

    myResponseWrite.Flush();
   ```

Output I'm getting is 728484804749464932504848327975131067108105101110116583278101..

**EDIT2:**

BinaryWriter solved my second problem.

Comment: Encoding is for text, definitely not for images. Use a byte array instead.

Comment: Why would you pass any binary data through an encoder/decoder?

Comment: Thanks! What other way can I get it into an byte array?

Comment: Thats the first thing I thought. Why use char arrays for binary data?!

Comment: strongly recommend you use [SuperSocket](http://supersocket.coldplex.com), It will significantly save your time when you do .NET socket development.

Comment: socketData.dataBuffer is already byte[], no conversion required!

Comment: @user1015551 - In order to know how to get the `byte[]` we'll need to see more code (most likely your `onReceive` callback method at least).

Comment: Not to nitpick, but there's no such thing as "C# sockets". You mean ".NET Sockets".

Comment: SuperSocket url should be http://supersocket.codeplex.com

Comment: SuperSocket's architecture might be a bit intimidating - Lidgren's networking library is much easier to use (depending on how extensible this needs to be): http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/

Comment: What type is socketData?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Shouldn't they both be removed anyway since they're tags?

Comment: @user1015551 - 1. `StreamWriter` is only applicable to text (again...). 2. Your question is missing the context required to properly answer it. What do you mean you are getting numbers? I thought the bytes from the `byte[]` were going to be passed through to a proxied connection. If you are simply reading from one socket and passing the bytes through to another, then this should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: @M.Babcock: maybe. Or just rewritten

Comment: @user1015551 - Please be sure to answer your question documenting the detail necessary to learn from your question. Bare in mind, when asking questions in the future, it is as important to disclose what you're *currently* doing as it is to describe what you *want* to be doing. Failing to do so leads to hard to answer questions.

Answer (score 1):

[Convert.ToBase64String Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and its inverse FromBase64String can help you go between byte arrays and strings, if that's how you want to transfer the data, say if you were planning to attach it to a plain text email for instance.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot use base64, because I would have to build the whole buffer before doing base64decode. I need the data to be written 'live'

Comment: In Base64, each 6-bit group is used as an index into an array of 64 printable characters (8 bits each). Hence, every 4 base64 encoded bytes can be decoded into the 3 original bytes. This means that *you do not need to build the complete hold buffer* to decode base64. All you need is to chunk your decoding in 4 byte blocks and then pass these on to the Convert.FromBase64 class to do the conversion for you. This essentially is streamed decoding and would be a good idea to wrap the logic in a Base64EncodedStream, descending Stream